# How to Properly Plot an SVM Model in R?

Tags: r, plot, model, classification, svm

I am running an SVM model with 4 numerical columns and 1 column that is a factor. I am able to see a successful summary of the model, and the accuracy is perfect.

However, when trying to plot the model with 4 variables I get a result that does not look right, as the data points are not grouped by classification. Here is the code I've been using, if anyone could help that would be much appreciated. Also, let me know if the dataset is required for you to help me solve this issue.

```
View(anthrokids)

anthrokids$Race <- as.factor(anthrokids$Race)


svm_model <- svm(formula = Race ~ ., data = anthrokids)
summary(svm_model)

svm_model$SV


plot(svm_model, data = anthrokids, Height~Weight, 
 slice = list(Age = 3, Sex = 4))


prediction = predict(svm_model, anthrokids)
table(Predicted = prediction, Actual = anthrokids$Race)
```

Comment: I mean it's really hard to see what's going on without a reproducible example. But plotting a four dimensional space in two dimensions is a tough problem, not really specific to SVM. You are only using two variables for the plot and it's possible the slices you've chosen aren't really representative of the underlying data. I'm not sure there is a "proper" way and that seems like an opinion based question anyway which is off topic for Stack Overflow.  If you want more general discussions about interpreting SVMs, then maybe it would be better to ask at [stats.se] instead.

Comment: @MrFlick I guess a reproducible example would be using the iris dataset in R. I've used the same code there and it works perfect. What did you mean by the slices not being representative by the data?

Comment: I was referring to the `slice = list(Age = 3, Sex = 4)` part. Not sure how you chose those values. It it works fine with iris, then it must be something about your data specifically. And it's hard to say what what might be without seeing your data.

Comment: Oh, okay I see. I attached a Google Sheet with the dataset I'm using. If you're able to tell me how to include the other variables after seeing the data please let me know! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S15H64YpcSLWlOJ0O0pDi5K6xafLd4-tDQcIdYlwNGU/edit?usp=sharing